# Azure notiication hub java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information

Tags: java, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to connect Azure notification hub through java to send some notifications to mobile, I am getting the exception as Exception in thread "main" 
`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out:` no further information, While the .Net developer was able to connect and push the notification.

Below is code I am using, Kindly help resolving the issue, thanks.

```
    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.windowsazure</groupId>
          <artifactId>NotificationHubs</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    NotificationHub hub = new NotificationHub("Endpoint=sb://xxx.sbus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=abccddsd", "xxxx");
    Set<String> tags = new HashSet<String>();
          tags.add("test");
    String message = "{\"data\":{\"msg\":\"Hello from Java!\"}}";
    Notification andriodN = Notification.createGcmNotification(message);
    hub.sendNotification(andriodN, tags);
```

Comment: I am still struck at same issue, Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It says `Connection timed out`. Check if your server is online and is accessible from the given device. Also check for typos in the URL.

Comment: I have resolved the issue by connecting through proxy
CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpClient = HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create()
    .setProxy(new HttpHost(PROXY_HOST,PROXY_PORT)).build();
  httpClient.start();
  HttpClientManager.setHttpAsyncClient(httpClient);